SSIS package error: Too many bind variables
I have created a SSIS package where i have a ADO NET Source (SQL Server) and and ADO NET Destination (Oracle). I extract data from source with a SQL statement (below) defined in source (around 73000 rows) and map the columns in destination. Everything is ok until i execute the package and it shows me error: [ADO NET Destination [2]] Error: An exception has occurred during data insertion, the message returned from the provider is: ORA-06550: line 10086, column 274:
PLS-00183: too many bind variables
I have tried other packages which have less rows for processing and it goes ok, data are inserted successfully.
I have checked all data types and they match between source and destination, also the number of columns is ok. There are 12 columns and i don't have a WHERE clause in the SQL statement Also i tried to create a For Loop container inside the package but same error again.
SELECT DISTINCT 
 sps.payment
,c.customer_text
,sps.amount
,sps.date
,sps.user
,sps.end_date
,sps.start_date
,sps.status
,sps.regular_amount
,sps.last_amount
,sps.last_updated
,sps.updated_by
FROM oltp.dbo.payment_summary sps
INNER JOIN oltp.dbo.customer c on c.customer_id=sps.customer_id;


You haven't shown the code from the package that is causing the exception to be raised, including the insert statement you're using and how you're mapping and binding values, which will make it rather difficult to help you.

The only code is the query for extracting data from source, the rest is automatic in SSIS by connecting source with destination, also take under consideration that mappings are done correctly 100% sure.

Then you will have to debug what it is actually executing when it errors. Once you know what it is going wrong you might then be able to figure out why. You've asserted that everything is correct but that doesn't seem to be the case, or it would work.

Have you tried looking up the Oracle error messages yet? PLS-00183: too many bind variables Cause: The library unit used more bind variables than permitted. (The current limit is 65535 bind variables in one library unit.) For 12 columns you'd probably max out at 5,461 rows in a single insert with VALUES statement that uses placeholder binding.

Just curious why you're using ADO.NET to connect to Oracle instead of the Microsoft Oracle connector for SSIS?
